# Freehub stuck on wheel

Tags: mountain-bike, freewheel, freehub

The freehub doesn't quite roll as smoothly as before. Pedalling back actually turns the wheel back if it's free spinning. So we thought we'd take the body off to clean it and see if anythings broken or not. But it won't come of the wheel. I believe it should pull off, but with all my strength it doesn't. Tapping it with a hammer from the other side also wasn't fruitful. What else can we try to get it off? [image]

Comment: The freehub is normally bolted to the hub.  You will probably need some big hex tools in the middle to engage the fasteners.   If you can **identify a brand of your hub**, then there may be documentation like service manuals to consult.   Remember, there will be a hundred tiny ball bearings inside this thing.

Comment: There's no hex key 'slot' though, the axle is perfectly round straight through.

Comment: There's also no name markers on the freehub. It is a Alchemist X-Sense wheel.

Comment: There are several different schemes for attaching the freehub.  Without knowing the specific model or being able to touch it there's no way for us to know.

Comment: Freehubs will turn backwards a bit if you pedal backwards -- this is normal.   But, you shouldn't have strong engagement when pedaling backwards. And a hammer is not really the tool to use (unless your name is Jeremy Clarkson).

Comment: Try contacting the manufacturer of your wheel.   http://www.alchemistbikes.com/?lang=en   may be a good starting point.

Comment: Some freehubs also thread in/out